# Capturing answer via mobile link on whatsapp?

Tags: java, android, hyperlink, whatsapp

Say, one would like to build an app for a phone that lets someone  send a question via whatsapp to their friends. For example:

> > What is your favorit color? 
> >     [red](http://Red) or [blue](http://blue)

In that app that person would like to keep track of their friends answers.
I was just wondering whether this is even possible and how one would be able to do such a thing via a link or are there even better options out there?

Edit:
Maybe my question was not all too clear. I do understand how to send a whatsapp message from an app but the question was more directed to how to register an answer through a link.

Answer (score 0):

WhatsApp doesn't offer public APIs and there is no way you can access WhatsApp data in your App. It only allows you to send messages to a person using the person's number. As per WhatsApp's documentation,

> WhatsApp's Click to Chat feature allows you to begin a chat with
>   someone without having their phone number saved in your phone's
>   address book. As long as you know this person’s phone number, you can
>   create a link that will allow you to start a chat with them.
>
> To create your own link, use https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=
>   followed by the person's full phone number in international format.

For details, check the WhatsApp's documentation here: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/?category=5245251